# Javascript working on local, not working online

Tags: javascript

I've just uploaded my website and something is wrong. I have a smooth scrolling when clicking in the navigation menù, and it worked on local (I used brackets), now it's not. Also, when I access to the site from my phone, the menù doesn't open.
Can someone help please? The site is http://www.chiarabonsignore.com

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/218196)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that on your website you forgot to upload the following file: 
`http://www.chiarabonsignore.com/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Because I get the following error:
**"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.chiarabonsignore.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"**

I'd also suggest checking [this link out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, yes, it actually make sense not linking a website just like that, I'm sorry! I've seen it done before so I thought it was ok.
By the way, yes, that was the problem, thank you!

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at your website in Firefox, it seems to be larger than in Chrome.

Comment: ouch! thanks for for letting me know!